# supervisor won't give meaningful output

Tags: bash, docker, supervisord

have a docker file set up to launch a `supervisord` instance inside of ubuntu under virtualbox with the following config:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:install]
command=bash -c "/src/etc/install.sh"
directory=/src/etc/
autorestart=true
autostart=true
stopwaitsecs=90
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp_install.log
```

that is set to launch the following test script file from my `src/etc/` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "testing"
```

When I launch `/usr/local/bin/supervisord`, I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:295: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2014-03-16 00:56:40,709 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2014-03-16 00:56:40,723 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2014-03-16 00:56:41,728 INFO spawned: 'install' with pid 8
2014-03-16 00:56:42,730 INFO success: install entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

At which point, the application hangs indefinitely.

If I try to get a `ls` of the `/var/log` directory, there's no evidence that the `myapp_install.log` file was ever created.

Obviously I've not set up my `supervisord.conf` file correctly, but it's really odd that it's telling me that it's launched the script successfully and then hangs until I `ctrl-c`.

Comment: What happens if change your script to:  `touch /tmp/foobar` ?  Does the file get created?

Comment: it does not, actually

Comment: Crazy idea then, could it be install.sh is not executable?  (don't hate me if I'm right;)

Comment: no I think it's executable -- turns out the script wasn't running unless I had `command=/bin/bash -c "/src/etc/install.sh"`. Also seem to be having trouble getting subsequent parts of the script to run as a different user.

Comment: What is install.sh doing ? Can you post it's content say on github ?